# Data concatenation in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have two data columns in SPSS

```
hhid = 1 2 3

carid = 26 27 28
```

I want to create a new column which concatenates both the hhid and carid and gives me an output

```
Newid = 1_26 2_27 3_28
```

I am new to SPSS, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The following code assumes, that your id variables are numeric. Otherwise just delete the `STRING` functions from the `COMPUTE` command.

```
* generate a string variable of 17 characters. Adjust length as you wish.
STRING Newid (A17).
COMPUTE Newid = CONCAT(LTRIM(STRING(hhid,F8)), "_", LTRIM(STRING(carid,F8))).
EXECUTE.
```

Explanation: The `STRING(var,format)` function transforms the numeric value of "var" into a string of the given format. In the code above the format is an 8 digit number without any decimals. The Output of this function is an 8 character long string with leading blanks. To delete the leading blanks, this function is wrapped in the `LTRIM(string)` function.

Comment: @user3637176 If you find an answer correct and useful please consider to mark it as "accepted answer". This would help other users to recognise it as a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

In SPSS Modeler, you can attach a Derive node to your stream to create your new variable, ie. your concatenated variable.  When you double click to open the Derive node you can either enter your own syntax, ie.

```
    hhid><"_"><cardid
```

or [you can click on the expression builder to help you through this.  I've put a red circle around the expression builder in the image from this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ2u1.png)